# "File `realcalc.tex' not found" - after texlive-generic-extra installed?

Tags: errors, installing, ubuntu

*Disclosure: my knowledge of LaTeX is extremely limited*

I am trying to use `pdflatex` to convert `foo.tex` to `foo.pdf`.

When I first tried this I got error messages saying I was missing `calc.sty` so I installed `texlive-latex-extra`.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Then I got error messages saying

> ! LaTeX Error: File `realcalc.tex' not
>   found

So I installed `texlive-generic-extra`

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-generic-extra
```

and I still get that error message.

I read that it's necessary when packages are install to rebuild the LaTeX package database so I ran `texhash` but I still get the `realcalc` error.

Can anyone tell me what I should do to resolve this ?

FWIW the input `.txt` which I'm trying to convert looks like this :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nzinvoice}
\renewcommand{\InvoiceNumber}{91}
\renewcommand{\CustomerName}{Teast Ltd}
\renewcommand{\DueDate}{September 20, 2012}
\renewcommand{\CustomerAddress}{PO Box 666\\
Somewhere\\
Someplace
}

\begin{document}
\begin{invoice}{NZ\string$}{0}
  \ProjectTitle{}
  \vfill
  \Fee{Doughnuts}{2500.00}{1}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

---

*After [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68215/17885):*

Herbert I grabbed the file from CTAN . But I found there was no `$TEXMFLOCAL/tex/generic/realcalc` as you can see below (I mean I could create those directories subsidiary to `$TEXMFLOCAL` but I didn't think that was what you intended ?):

```
glauc@ubserver1:~/texmf$ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/share/texmf
glauc@ubserver1:~/texmf$ cd /usr/local/share/texmf
glauc@ubserver1:/usr/local/share/texmf$ ls -lrt
total 8
drwx--S--- 2 root staff 4096 Aug 22 23:29 lsR16767.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root staff   81 Aug 23 10:01 ls-R
glauc@ubserver1:/usr/local/share/texmf$
```

So after that I thought I would fall back to trying your non-root version.

```
glauc@ubserver1:/usr/local/share/texmf$ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
/home/glauc/texmf
```

So I created the `texmf` directory and unpacked the `.zip` from CTAN there to make a structure like this :

```
glauc@ubserver1:~$ ls -lR ~/texmf
/home/glauc/texmf:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 glauc glauc 4096 Aug 23 12:51 realcalc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 glauc glauc 6648 Sep 25  2005 realcalc.zip

/home/glauc/texmf/realcalc:
total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 glauc glauc  1456 Feb 15  1993 readme
-rw-r--r-- 1 glauc glauc 14159 Feb 15  1993 realcalc.tex
-rw-r--r-- 1 glauc glauc    98 Feb 15  1993 realdemo.tex
-rw-r--r-- 1 glauc glauc  8796 Feb 15  1993 realtest.tex
```

And I then did a `texhash` from `/home/glauc/texmf` specifying both `.` and `./realcalc` as directories to process.

Sadly nothing has changed !

If you can see anything I'm obviously doing wrong here I'd be be grateful to hear !

Answer (score 4):

the file isn't part of the TeXLive distribution. Get it from CTAN: ftp://mirror.ctan.org/macros/generic/realcalc.zip and save it into `$TEXMFLOCAL/tex/generic/realcalc`. Then run `texhash` and it should be found by `kpsewhich realcalc.tex`. 
The directory for TEXMFLOCAL can be found with `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`. If you have no root access then install it under TEXMFHOME `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`, which is often `$HOME/texmf`

Comment: OK, thank you very much for that. I appreciate it. I've still got problems and I'm about to amend the question to explain those. If you were willing to comment on those that would be great.

Comment: the directory should be `/home/glauc/texmf/tex/generic/realcalc`

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I don't have time to try that right during today but I will have a go. Thanks again for your helpful comments.